# Go's LeftStr, RightStr, SubStr

Tags: string, go

I believe there are no `LeftStr(str,n)` (take at most n first characters), `RightStr(str,n)` (take at most n last characters) and `SubStr(str,pos,n)` (take first n characters after pos) function in Go, so I tried to make one

```
// take at most n first characters
func Left(str string, num int) string {
    if num <= 0 {
        return ``
    }
    if num > len(str) {
        num = len(str)
    }
    return str[:num]
}

// take at most last n characters
func Right(str string, num int) string {
    if num <= 0 {
        return ``
    }
    max := len(str)
    if num > max {
        num = max
    }
    num = max - num
    return str[num:]
}
```

But I believe those functions will give incorrect output when the string contains unicode characters. What's the fastest solution for those function, is using `for range` loop is the only way?

Comment: The `for range` loop is not the only way, you could simply convert the `string` to a `[]rune`, and then you could apply the same slicing operations on that as you currently do in the `string` itself - except that it would be correct in any input `string` assuming it is normalized. Note that converting to `[]rune` would be slower for the `LeftStr()` implementation than the `for range`.

Comment: You might also want to consider how to handle [combining characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) - are they part of the num count, or should they be counted together with the character they modify.

Comment: It is not just combining characters as ANisus correctly stated: Emoji are coming to unicode and the may carry modifiers which you propably don't want to cut away. http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/tr51-2.html#Proposals

Comment: @Volker: Neat. I didn't know that. No more eurocentric emojis!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in already in comments,
[combining characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character), modifying runes, and other multi-rune
["characters"](https://blog.golang.org/normalization#TOC_5.)
can cause difficulties.

Anyone interested in Unicode handling in Go should probably read the Go Blog articles
["Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go"](https://blog.golang.org/strings)
and ["Text normalization in Go"](https://blog.golang.org/normalization).
In particular, the later talks about the [`golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm/) package which can help in handling some of this.

You can consider several levels increasingly of more accurate (or increasingly more Unicode aware) spiting the first (or last) "n characters" from a string.

1. Just use n bytes.
   This may split in the middle of a rune but is O(1), is very simple, and in many cases you know the input consists of only single byte runes.
   E.g. `str[:n]`.
2. Split after n runes.
   This may split in the middle of a character. This can be done easily, but at the expense of copying and converting with just `string([]rune(str)[:n])`.
   You can avoid the conversion and copying by using the [`unicode/utf8`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/) package's `DecodeRuneInString` (and `DecodeLastRuneInString`) functions to get the length of each of the first n runes in turn and then return `str[:sum]` (O(n), no allocation).
3. Split after the n'th "boundary".
   One way to do this is to use
   [`norm.NFC.FirstBoundaryInString(str)`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm#Form.FirstBoundaryInString) repeatedly
   or [`norm.Iter`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm#Iter) to find the byte position to split at and then return `str[:pos]`.

Consider the displayed string "cafés" which could be represented in Go code as: "cafés", "caf\u00E9s", or "caf\xc3\xa9s" which all result in the identical six bytes. Alternative it could represented as "cafe\u0301s" or "cafe\xcc\x81s" which both result in the identical seven bytes.

The first "method" above may split those into "caf\xc3"+"\xa9s" and cafe\xcc"+"\x81s".

The second may split them into "caf\u00E9"+"s" ("café"+"s") and "cafe"+"\u0301s" ("cafe"+"́s").

The third should split them into "caf\u00E9"+"s" and "cafe\u0301"+"s" (both shown as "café"+"s").